# If then is not giving expected results - laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a notification table, where each row will show a different notification to the user. I'm trying to do the part where if there is a value of 1 in a row, then show a sentence, while if there is a value of 2 then show another sentence. And if I have 2 rows where one of them has 1 while the other with 2 , then show both rows.

Any idea why the following code is always giving an output of "number 1" although there are "number 2" values in the table ?

```
 @foreach(auth()->user()->notifics as $notification)

 @if(Auth::user()->notifics()->where('data_type', 1)->first()->exists())

        <a href="#"> number 1</a>
@elseif(Auth::user()->notifics()->where('data_type', 2)->first()->exists())
        <a href="#"> number 2</a>
@endif

@endforeach
```

Comment: Because the `elseif` doesn't run if the `if` condition was true. Same goes for `else`.

Comment: What would be the solution ?

Comment: Dunno. Depends what you're actually trying to achieve. At this point it sounds like logically it's working as expected.

Comment: I need to show all "data_type" , either 1 or 2.

Comment: You're showing either 1, or 2 or nothing, so sounds fine. Do you mean you want to show `number 1`, _and_ `number 2`?

Comment: If the table has fields of 1 and 2, then display both number 1 and number 2, not just number 1.

Comment: Split it into 2 `if` blocks then without the `elseif`.

Comment: It did split them, and now both are showing, but each showing two times instead of once. I have only one record for 1 and one record for 2.

Comment: Then your foreach is running twice. You need to think about what your code is doing. Here's a question, are you actually intending on checking whether $notification is of data_type 1 or 2, not just that the DB table contains at least one?

Comment: This is a notification table, where each row will show a different notification to the user. I'm trying to do the part where if there is a value of 1 in a row, then show a sentence, while if there is a value of 2 then show another sentence. And if I have 2 rows where one of them has 1 while the other with 2 , then show both.

Comment: Okay, but is `auth()->user()->notifics` not an array of the notifications you want to show?

Comment: notifics is a class in the User model as follows  :                            
   public function notifics()
    {

      return $this->hasMany('App\Notif', 'rec_uid');
    }

Comment: I'm returning all rows that match

Comment: Can you get a `var_dump` of `$notification`?

Comment: Wouldnt it be enough just to convert the elseif to an if?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is updated according to the feedback. The code should be:

```
@foreach(auth()->user()->notifics as $notification)

@if($notification->data_type==1)
        <a href="#"> number 1</a>
@elseif($notification->data_type==2)
        <a href="#"> number 2</a>
@endif

@endforeach
```

As you are trying to iterate through your user's notification, in each of the loop, you should directly check the attribute of the notification by using `$notification->data_type`.

In your previous code, you constantly check if the user has a type of notification **in every loop**. So if a user has both types of notification and he has 2 notification records, it will show both of them **twice**. I am glad this helps, cheers!

Comment: It did split them, and now both are showing, but each showing two times instead of once. I have only one record for 1 and one record for 2, but each showing 2 times.

Comment: Owh, I'm sorry I might not get your idea correctly. But can you try this \ `@foreach(auth()->user()->notifics as $notification)

@if($notification->data_type==1)
        <a href="#"> number 1</a>
@elseif($notification->data_type==2)
        <a href="#"> number 2</a>
@endif

@endforeach`

Comment: Cool! Do you mind marking this as the correct answer? ;) Thank you very much for that fam

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change your if statements. Don't make your code complex. Sometimes code is actually easier than what we are expecting it to be :p

```
$notification->data_type==1

$notification->data_type==2
```

You just need to access the attribute directly by these changes in if and ifelse statements directly.